# Múltiples líneas / series de datos del archivo JSON con Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

He visto algunos ejemplos en varias líneas en un gráfico y he hecho algunos gráficos circulares y de barras fáciles de archivos JSON en Chart.js.

Actualmente, las barras y gráficos circulares fáciles son así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var chartColors =   {
            red: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            blue: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            yellow: 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 1)',
            green: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            purple: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            orange: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            darkgrey: 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)',
            maroon: 'rgba(200, 112, 91, 1)',
            khaki: 'rgba(190, 204, 200, 1)'
                             };

            $.ajax({ 
                url:'../graficas/contAvance.php',
                method: "GET",
                success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                data = JSON.parse(response);
                var nombre = [];
                var porcentaje = [];
                var curso = [];

                for (var i in data){
                    nombre.push(data[i].nombre+" "+data[i].ap_p);
                    porcentaje.push(data[i].porcentaje);
                    curso.push(data[i].curso_nombre); 
                                    }

                var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext('2d');
                var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2,{
                    type: 'horizontalBar',
                    data: 
                    {
                        labels: nombre,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Porcentaje %:',
                                backgroundColor: 
                                [
                                    chartColors.red,
                                    chartColors.blue,
                                    chartColors.yellow,
                                    chartColors.green,
                                    chartColors.purple,
                                    chartColors.orange,
                                    chartColors.darkgrey,
                                    chartColors.maroon,
                                    chartColors.khaki

                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                data: porcentaje
                                }
                                ]
                    },

                    options:{
                        responsive: true,


                        legend: {
                            display: false
                                },

                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false
                                       }
                                    }],

                            yAxes:  [{
                               gridLines: {
                                    display: false
                                          },

                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true,

                                   }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                            });

                        },
                    error: function() {
                            alert("Hay problemas al cargar la gráfica!");
                        }

                  });                       
            });
```

Pero no puedo imaginar cómo iniciar o formatear mis archivos JSON para varias líneas. ¿Necesito tener varios archivos JSON, uno para cada línea? Si es así, ¿cómo lo cargaría en mi canvas?

¿O puedo formatear mi archivo JSON de una manera que pueda usar solo un archivo para varias líneas? He visto este ejemplo: https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/pbYGVa pero todavía no estoy seguro de cómo obtener JSON y varias líneas juntas

Mis datos (JSON encode) son así y lo que mostraría en la gráfica sería el nombre de estudiante más el curso y el porcentaje de avance:

```
[{
   "curso_id":"4",
   "curso_nombre":"Test",
   "nombre":"Estudiante",
   "ap_p":"A_P",
   "usuario_id":"2",
   "total_temas":"7",
   "temas_vistos":"3",
   "porcentaje":"42.8571"},

 {
     "curso_id":"5",
     "curso_nombre":"Excel",
     "nombre":"Estudiante",
     "ap_p":"A_P",
     "usuario_id":"2",
     "total_temas":"2",
     "temas_vistos":"2",
     "porcentaje":"100.0000"},

{
     "curso_id":"4",
     "curso_nombre":"Test",
     "nombre":"Estudiante No. 2",
     "ap_p":"AP",
     "usuario_id":"3",
     "total_temas":"7",
     "temas_vistos":"6",
     "porcentaje":"85.7143"}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cargar el fichero JSON (Mediante un input file por ejemplo) y una vez cargado crear una expresion regular para separar cada línea del fichero. Después dividir cada línea en 3 partes ("parte1" ":" "parte3") y utilizar la **parte1** y la **parte3** para crear una tabla.

```
 function crearTabla(contenidoJSON){
                //Creamos un array por cada linea del fichero JS
                var lineas=[];

                //Creamos una expresion regular que nos divida cada linea deseada del fichero.
                var patron = /".+":".+"/gmi;
                //Añadimos cada coincidencia al array de lineas:
                lineas = contenidoJSON.match(patron);                

                //Recorremos el array:
                for(var i =0;i<lineas.length;i++){
                    //Creamos una expresion regular para seprar cada elemento del array en 3 partes por cada linea.
                    var patron1 = /(".+")(:)(".+")/;
                    var linea = lineas[i].match(patron1);

                    //Cada linea está formada por "elemtno" ":" "valor"
                    var primerElemento = linea[1];
                    var segundoElemento = linea[3];

                    console.log(primerElemento + segundoElemento);

                    //Una vez aqui podrias crear la tabla utilizando cada elemento.                                
                }
```

Una vez en este punto tendrás los elementos separados, y no hace falta tener un fichero JSON por cada línea, ya que tienes cada línea en un array, y luego separada en 3 partes que podrás usar a tu conveniencia para crear la tabla.

Al ejecutar el fragmento de codigo anterior, se podría ver por consola la salida, sería algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
"curso_id""4"
"curso_nombre""Test"
"nombre""Estudiante"
"ap_p""A_P"
"usuario_id""2"
"total_temas""7"
"temas_vistos""3"
"porcentaje""42.8571"
"curso_id""5"
"curso_nombre""Excel"
"nombre""Estudiante"
"ap_p""A_P"
"usuario_id""2"
"total_temas""2"
"temas_vistos""2"
"porcentaje""100.0000"
"curso_id""4"
"curso_nombre""Test"
"nombre""Estudiante No.2"
"ap_p""AP"
"usuario_id""3"
"total_temas""7"
"temas_vistos""6"
"porcentaje""85.7143"
```

Con cada uno de esos strings podrías crear las tablas sin necesidad de tener un archivo JSON por línea.

Comment: Gracias, intentaré hacerlo.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado no olvides marcarla con el tick verde. @EnriqueE.Molina